# how to refresh web page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, url, hash

I want to refresh a web page using javascript and, I knew how to do it but I have one problem,
before refresh:

> url: http://www.example.com/index.html#introduction

after refreshed:

> url: http://www.example.com/index.html

I want to use that hash as parameter in another javascript function after page has refreshed.

So, how can I save that hash after the page is reloaded?

Comment: r u using any server-side language?

Comment: How did you refreshed the page? Please show code!

Comment: nope, javascript only.

Comment: @Sankalp Mishra i know only basic method to refresh. something like location.reload().

Comment: if u use only static code then u need to use cookies(if also support legacy browsers) else u can use localstorage(for modern browsers) for storing the hashValue.

Comment: i have given an answer please check that

Answer (score 0):

I belive you have implemented refresh using location.reload() method, instead try redirecting to the same page using location.href like below.

location.href = "http://example.com/index.html#introduction"

This will refresh the page and also maintains # in url.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, if u use only static code then u need to use cookies(if also support legacy browsers) else u can use localstorage(for modern browsers) for storing the hashValue.

to reload without hashvalue use the following code

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.split("#")[0];
```

before calling the above code u need to save the hashValue.

```
var hash = location.hash.substr(1);
localStorage["hashValue"] = hash;
```

retrive the above value later as

```
var hash = localStorage["hashValue"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
escape(window.location.href)
```

if you want to add parameters:
for example

```
escape(window.location.href="parameter="+param);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
window.location.href = window.location
```